# Parent Directory is not Writable Error Android Emulator

Tags: android, file, writable

Getting "Parent directory of file is not writable" when trying to create a temp file. I am using Eclipse and the emulator.  I am using the permission in my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Here is the code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void sendEmail() {
    Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
    Log.d(TAG, "Path:" + Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/GPSTracking/" + MakeTextDate(today) + ".csv");
    File tempFile = null;
    try { 

        tempFile.createTempFile(MakeTextDate(today), ".csv");
        FileWriter out = FormatEmail(tempFile);
    }
    catch (IOException e) { 
        // error
        Log.d(TAG, "create temp file:" + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "Trip report");
        emailIntent
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here is your Trips Report");

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(tempFile));
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "SD Card" setting for your Virtual Device?

Comment: I don't know what you mean?

Comment: Eclipse -> Android Device Manager -> select the virtual device your emulator is running on -> Edit -> you have the settings page that you filled in when you created the virtual device. There you have the SD Card settings.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have fixed it.  Make it an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create file in root directory of storage, not sd-card

```
tempFile.createTempFile(MakeTextDate(today), ".csv");
```

Create file as you writing log with full path to external storage.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to say.  I tried adding Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + MakeTextDate(today), ".csv" and now it says that that directory does not exist:  /sdcard/sdcard/5-18-2013.csv

Comment: Indeed, you seem to construct a nice path to log, but nor for the actual file...  And even with that, you'll have to make sure you create the GPSTracking directory if it doesn't already exist.  And of course you need external storage permission in the Manifest.